# How to properly add my styles overriding current styles

Tags: wp-enqueue-style, css

I have a WP website: after reading docs everywhere, I made up a little, personal plugin that lets me display a particular app, made with VueJS, into a single Page.

Now, the theme of this website is a commercial one.

I red I can add my styles using `wp_enqueue_style`: my idea was to override some of the theme styles, but [in the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) I found wp_enqueue_style:

```
Registers the style if source provided (does NOT overwrite) and enqueues.
```

So, as I understand, I can't use this method to overwrite the current style (default theme) of the website.

What should I do to properly style my HTML? Consider one thing: the style must be applied only to one page, I don't need it "globally" (it should simply style my app inside my page, that's it).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to build a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to prevent your changes being overwritten when the theme is updated. This child theme needs only to consist of a `functions.php` file and a stylesheet that you **don't** name `style.css` to prevent it from being loaded automatically.

In your functions file you load the stylesheet only for this specific page, like this:

```
add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts','wpse278950_add_my_style');
function wpse278950_add_styles () {
  if is_single ('slug-of-your-page')
    wp_register_style ('my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my-style.css');
  }
}
```

Note: I didn't test the code, it might need debugging.

Comment: Ok, during the last day, I started doing it, but suddenly I stopped when I discovered I could enqueue styles at a higher priority using:

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myEnqueueFunction', 10);

Of course, this is less elegant than the child-theme option, but I only had 4 css rules to overwrite...